# How do I create bones that can properly control a robot leg?

Tags: animation, rigging, bones

[image]

[image]

Been trying to figure out how to properly rig this leg of a mesh. I have problem with the bones connecting to the foot, as there are two bones connected to foot they don't follow movement of leg properly. For example when I move the foot I want both of the two two parts connected to the foot to move with it. As can be seen in the bottom picture the parts doesn't quite stay connected with the foot.

Comment: Can you please add more details to your question?